# How to execute some code in directive after component view init in angular

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 8 and I have a component to which I added my own directive. I'm looking for a way that I will be able to call function in the body of the directive after component(which has this directive) view init. This function must be called from the directive, not from the component, because I use this directive in various components.

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. What is "the body of the directive"? Do you want to execute some code during the lifecycle events such as ngOnInit of the directive?

Comment: Directives have lifecycle hooks. You can write a `ngAfterViewInit()` in the body of the directive.

Comment: "body of the directive" means here -> export class MyDirective{...}. I want to execute code during the lifecycle events. Not lifecycle events of directive, but in component lifecycle.

Comment: @WillAlexander not directive lifecycle, but component lifecycle. Code must be in the directive

Comment: @WillAlexander In my case directive is init before component will be created

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to execute code inside of the Directive, it has the same lifecycle hooks as a component. From the documentation on [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#other-angular-lifecycle-hooks):

> A directive has the same set of lifecycle hooks.

Which means that you can create a Directive and give it an ngAfterViewInit hook like this:

```js
import { Directive, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[your-selector]'
})
export class YourDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Your code here
  }

}
```

Comment: The only change I'd make is using `ngAfterViewInit`, seeing as that seems to be the hook the OP wants.

Comment: @WillAlexander read my comments. This is definitely not what I am looking for. I tried this and it doesn't work, because the component is not yet created.

Comment: That's strange because in the documentation I linked they use this method to log when a component is initialized and destroyed, from the directive. https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#spying-oninit-and-ondestroy

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper hi, I probably know why it doesn't work.
I have this in my code:

@ContentChild(MatSelect) select: MatSelect;
I am looking for evnets that execute after select will be created. Any ideas now?

Comment: Possibly using AfterContentChecked? Could you describe exactly what you are trying to achieve? There may be a different approach